# How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to retrieve the HTML code of a link (web page) in PHP. For example, if the link is

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

then I want the HTML code of the page which is served. I want to retrieve this HTML code and store it in a PHP variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please explain it more.

You want to send a web request to a given URL and read the response to a Variable I guess?

Comment: Yes, same thing I want, i want the whole source code in a variable returned by that web request.

Comment: You could use [this tool](http://codecanyon.net/item/javascript-web-scraper/8598806) to easily scrap html.

Comment: Even with allow_url_fopen set to true, this function doesn't return the HTML of the page? What else should I check?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If your PHP server allows url fopen wrappers then the simplest way is:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
```

If you need more control then you should look at the [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl) functions:

```
$c = curl_init('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
```

Comment: I am worried about 404. In case the link does not exists, then I don't want its content, instead I want to display an error message ?? How we'll find that the url is giving 404 error or not (simply menas URL is working or not)?

Comment: @Prashant: I've edited to add a curl_getinfo call which will give you 200 or 404 or whatever

Comment: Also how is it possible PHP get the current page HTML?

Comment: Is this cross-domain?

Comment: Won't work on PHP7. Checked the php.ini and fopen is On.

Comment: Even with allow_url_fopen set to true, this function doesn't return the HTML of the page? What else should I check? I'm using PHP 7.2

Answer (score 25):

Also if you want to manipulate the retrieved page somehow, you might want to try some php DOM parser.
I find [*PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser*](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)  very easy to use.

Answer (score 12):

**Simple way:** Use [`file_get_contents()`](http://de3.php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
```

Please note that `allow_url_fopen` must be `true` in you `php.ini` to be able to use URL-aware fopen wrappers.

**More advanced way:** If you cannot change your PHP configuration, `allow_url_fopen` is `false` by default and if ext/curl is installed, use the [`cURL` library](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to connect to the desired page.

Comment: Even with allow_url_fopen set to true, this function doesn't return the HTML of the page? What else should I check?

Answer (score 11):

You may want to check out the YQL libraries from Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql

The task at hand is as simple as

```
select * from html where url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
```

You can try this out in the console at: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console (requires login)

Also see Chris Heilmanns screencast for some nice ideas what more you can do: http://developer.yahoo.net/blogs/theater/archives/2009/04/screencast_collating_distributed_information.html

Answer (score 7):

Here is two different, **simple ways to get content from URL**:

1) the first method

Enable Allow_url_include from your hosting (php.ini or somewhere)

```
<?php
$variableee = readfile("http://example.com/");
echo $variableee;
?>
```

or

2)the second method

Enable php_curl, php_imap and php_openssl

```
<?php
// you can add anoother curl options too
// see here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
function get_dataa($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$variableee = get_dataa('http://example.com');
echo $variableee;
?>
```

Comment: Great, second method did the trick. Thanks, works great.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the DomDocument method to get an individual HTML tag level variable too

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($homepage);
$titles = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h3');
echo $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

look at this function:

http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 4):

you could use file_get_contents if you are wanting to store the source as a variable however curl is a better practive.

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
echo $url;
```

this solution will display the webpage on your site. However curl is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

You can get the whole HTML code as an array (parsed form) using this code
Download the 'simple_html_dom.php' file here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simple_html_dom.php/download

Answer (score 1):

`$output = file("http://www.example.com");` didn't work until I enabled: `allow_url_fopen, allow_url_include,` and `file_uploads` in `php.ini` for PHP7

Answer (score -2):

I tried this code and it's working for me .

```
$html = file_get_contents('www.google.com');
$myVar = htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES);
echo($myVar);
```