# PHP Get Contents of a URL or Page

Tags: php, html, curl

I am trying to create a PHP script which can request data, such as HTML content, from an external server, then do something with the received content. Here is a generalized example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
//Get the HTML generated by http://api.somesite.com/

//Now tack on the Unix timestamp of when the data was received
$myFetchedData = $dataFromExternalServer . "\n Data received at: ". time();

echo $myFetchedData;
```

I'm thinking I should use curl in here somewhere, but I am not sure after that. Could someone post a generalized example of how I could do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you only need GET and `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on your server, you can simply use

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.somesite.com');
```

Comment: Yes, I just need a simple GET request. I know allow_url_fopen isn't enabled by default on some web-hosts, especially on the budget hosts. To allow maximum compatibility, which do you recommend, `file_get_contents()` or the curl library?

Comment: Curl might also be missing. So you probably want to use whatever's available.

Comment: between the two, if ur given the choice, file_get_contents is actually the better method

Comment: @Ascherer Actually, I would think cURL is better. It seems to get better performance. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance).

Comment: for speed yeah, but not simplicity

Comment: Given the choice, I would pick cURL. You get a lot more control (should you ever need to use it) and it has more robust error handling. If you're GET'ing as part of loading your page you need to make sure you deal with what happens if that GET takes a very long time or fails.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is disabled on many servers because a lot of malicious attacks occur through it. Far better option is to use the cURL method suggested in the next answer

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen, the truth is only the CURL option works as it should. Using file_get_contents('URL') to fetch JSON open data from external URL is very tricky. On daytime, I get timeouts and errors, once every two or three attempts. At night it works like magic - but unpredictible magic.

Answer (score 11):

This is how you would use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get contents from a remote url. You would define the function and make calls like `url_get_contents("http://example.com/");`

```
function url_get_contents($url, $useragent='cURL', $headers=false, $follow_redirects=true, $debug=false) {

    // initialise the CURL library
    $ch = curl_init();

    // specify the URL to be retrieved
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    // we want to get the contents of the URL and store it in a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    // specify the useragent: this is a required courtesy to site owners
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

    // ignore SSL errors
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // return headers as requested
    if ($headers==true){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    }

    // only return headers
    if ($headers=='headers only') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY ,1);
    }

    // follow redirects - note this is disabled by default in most PHP installs from 4.4.4 up
    if ($follow_redirects==true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    }

    // if debugging, return an array with CURL's debug info and the URL contents
    if ($debug==true) {
        $result['contents']=curl_exec($ch);
        $result['info']=curl_getinfo($ch);
    }

    // otherwise just return the contents as a variable
    else $result=curl_exec($ch);

    // free resources
    curl_close($ch);

    // send back the data
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.url.com/cakephp/controller/action/param:1" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
$dataFromExternalServer=curl_exec($ch);
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Answer (score 6):

**simple methods**

```
<?php
echo readfile("http://example.com/");   //needs "Allow_url_include" enabled
//OR
echo include("http://example.com/");    //needs "Allow_url_include" enabled
//OR
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/");
//OR
echo stream_get_contents(fopen('http://example.com/', "rb")); //you may use "r" instead of "rb"  //needs "Allow_url_fopen" enabled
?>
```

**The best Way (using cURL)**:

```
echo get_remote_data('http://example.com');   //SIMPLE REQUEST;
//OR
echo get_remote_data('http://example.com', "var2=something&var3=blabla" ); //POST REQUEST;
```

(CODE: at [GitHub](https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/get-remote-url-content-data.php) )

Comment: Please don't make these kinds of edits, @solutioner. It would be preferable to flag this post as a duplicate.

Comment: An answer consisting solely of a link is not considered a good answer for [so].

Comment: Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, it doesn't look like echoing the return from an included file will do what you're implying it will do.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.somesite.com/');
$dataFromExternalServer = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You need to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );` or the returned data is sent to the client.

Comment: Yes of course, as well as a plethora of other curl options that can be set. I did say "put simply".

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP installation doesn't support curl and does not `allow_url_fopen`, here's an option if you have PECL:

```
$body = http_parse_message(http_get($url))->body;
```

Comment: `(PECL pecl_http >= 0.1.0)` - even more unlikely than curl or `allow_url_fopen`

Comment: My hosts have PECL, but I agree, it may be more of a long shot.

Comment: I agree, I was hoping to obtain maximum compatibility. Thanks though, Håvard!