# PHP code to get the HTML code of a webpage

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)

Is there a PHP code to get the HTML code of a webpage? 
$html = file_get_contents('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
this doesnt work. It simply loads the webpage. I want to display the HTML code when I run the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then dont view the output in the browser. Or send a text header.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code works with the given url. But it doesnt work with 'http://www.maduraonline.com/?find=home'. It simply displays the webpage. Any idea why that is?.I want the html code of this webpage as I'm developing a translator. What can I do to get its html code?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
$html = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'));
```

and try using the  tags to output it.

Answer (score 0):

Just HTML encode your output, so that & becomes &amp;, using the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

Answer (score -1):

```
$handle = @fopen("'http://www.webmasterworld.com", "rt");
$code = fread($handle,9000);
```

This is copied form another thread, but it should be good enough. It will get the code in $handle and then $code would contain 9000 bytes of that code.

Answer (score -2):

Try using exec and wget together:

```
<?php

exec('wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask -O', $array);

echo implode('<br />', $array);

?>
```