# Php_simple_html_dom on a table

Tags: php, web-scraping

I would like to extract data from a website, whose code is written like this:

```
...
<tr>
  <td class="something1"><a class="whatever" href="#">NAME</a>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="something2">DATA</td>
  <td class="something3">NUMERIC DATA</td>
</tr>
...
```

In particular, I have my *NAME* list from my MySQL database, and if my *NAME* is equal to *NAME* on this website, I want to print on my website the correspondent *NUMERIC DATA*.
I know I can do something with [php_simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but I cannot really achieve this action. Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. cURl request to get the HTML from the page. 2. load the returned document into a `DOMDocument`, 3. iterate each row, 4. compare the text of the a element within the td with a class of something1 against the result of the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to read NAME first. if relevant then read the rest? You can read a website Dom as explained here: [How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://pathToTheWebsite.com/thePage');
```

Now lets parse the `$html` with some regex. (you can use that library too, the documentation tells you how to do it!

```
preg_match('/<td class="something1"><a class="whatever" href="#">(?<name>\w)</a>&nbsp;</td>/', $html, $matches);
```

now `$matches['name']` will contain the NAME. You can do the same for the rest and maybe cleanup that regex a little this was just an example.