# Retrive an image from a local server and show it on the web via the public server

Tags: webserver

I have two servers one is strictly local and the other one is facing the public side. The local server generates a few images that I would like to show on my page (hosted by the public server). These images are dynamic, in other words they change every 5 minutes or so.

How would I go about retrieving an image from the local server and showing it to the public without port forwarding on the local server? I imagine some kind of proxy but I have no idea what to look at.

Both servers are running lighttpd. Public server runs on port 80 and 443 (port forwarded) and the local server runs on port 8080. These are separate physical machines on the same network and accessible by each other.

Comment: You probably need to run a server side language to be able to do that (although maybe someone will prove me wrong!) This post is PHP specific, but it may help give you some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php

Comment: That might just work. I will test it out and let you know.