# Google reCaptcha sitekey with domain

Tags: javascript, php, python, captcha

Is it possible to get Google reCaptcha sitekey only knowing the domain name of a given website where the sitekey is used but **without being abled to access the website directly**? Like doing a request to a Google api or something like that.

P.S. The public key would be enough, the private key is not needed of course.

Comment: For using Google reCaptcha, you need two keys, one public key and one private/secret key. While public key is available and visible on public domain, private key can only be accessed by site owner. So to answer to your question, **NO**, you can only see/access the public key but you cannot access/see the private key just by knowing the domain name.

Comment: The public key would be enough, I don't need the private one

Comment: Yes, you can access the public key from the site. Look for this line in the site `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public_key"></div>`

Comment: Yes but my question is if is possible to access it without being abled to access the website, so without viewing the HTML of the web page.

Comment: I don't think there's any in-built procedure where you can get the public key just by knowing the domain name. You need to, anyhow, scrub the webpage to find the key.

Comment: Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Search on Google, on how to scrub a web page. Here's a head start, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)

Comment: I know how to create a scraper, but I can't navigate to the webpage. I only know that a given domain name have a sitekey linked.