# Detect CSS class in a page and write if/else in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a page where I need to detect a CSS class and then apply if/else statement using PHP. How do I do that?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="insights">
        Hello World
    </div>
</body>
```

What would be the PHP code to detect and find "insights" class exists and show "yes, it exists". If there's no class of that name then show "No, it doesn't exists."

How should I achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something called a "DOM parser".

Comment: As a general concept, PHP is working on the server side while HTML renders on the client side. Hence, unless you are loading someone else's page,you should be able to know what you are going to render. If you are rendering another's person code: do not. But if you still do: get content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php - then apply RegEx to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just use `strpos`

```
$contains = str($html, 'class="insights"') !== false;
```

a more complex and robust solution would be, to use a regular expression like the following

```
class="[^"]*\binsights\b[^"]*"
```

this could be used in php like this

```
$contains = (bool) preg_match('/class="[^"]*\binsights\b[^"]*"/', $html);
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I write this in PHP with the else statement? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: `if ($contains) { echo "yes, it exists"; } else { echo "no, it don't exist"; }`

Answer (score 2):

There is a library that named Simple HTML DOM Parser. You can parse the dom with it and access elements that you wanted. In your case you can do something like that :

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$dom = str_get_html("<html><body><div class='insights'></div><div><div class='insights'></div></div></body></html>");

$elements = $dom->find('.insights');

echo count($elements) > 0 ? "It exists" : "No, it doesn't exists.";
```

If you want to fetch source from an url you can do it like that :

```
$dom = file_get_html('URL');
```