# Getting the DOM/HTML of a web page after being generated by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, dom

I am trying to generate a PDF from a PHP page. I have the code as below and it works. However, when trying to use the ob_get_clean() as I have seen others do I get a 500 error.

Ideas on other ways I can get the finished generated page? Can Javascript work?

The other issue is that the page requires a login and is also being generated by a POST form so the page can't be easily grabbed.

```
</html>
<?php
$content = "This will work";//ob_get_clean();
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

try {

    //ob_clean();
    $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/output.pdf', 'F');
} catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
    $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
    echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: If it's a 500, your error will be in the error_log. What does it say?

Comment: I looked and found nothing there

Comment: check phpinfo() and see where your error_log is set to, maybe even set a custom one with ini_set in your script.. Also, make sure error_reporting is set to -, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Like [that question in Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php) you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) if your server allow fopen or use [CURL](http://www.php.net/curl) (universal and best approach for me):

```
</html>
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$content = file_get_contents('yourphppage.php'); //first option
//OR CURL MODE
$c = curl_init('yourpage.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

$content = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
//execute your code bellow checking $status of cURL, else thrown an error

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

try {

    //ob_clean();
    $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/output.pdf', 'F');
} catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
    $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
    echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
}

?>
```

Or you can use Javascript using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) like [that example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript) in Stack:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor PS: An example if you want to take out some elements from the renderer
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```